# Constant '' " used before being initialized

Tags: api, swift, swift-3, io

Como consigo ter acesso a um atributo de uma classe em outra? Pode parecer bobo, mas to aprendendo agora swift e ainda me confundo com coisas simples.

To tentando fazer um app de filmes usando uma API. Tambem to usando o Alamofire.

Porem to problema ao tentar acessar o id de um filme. Na classe que faço a requisição para api preciso colocar o id do filme junto com a url (api solicita que faça dessa forma). E estou com dificuldade nisso.

Criei uma struct que consigo pegar todos os dados que a api retorna.

```
struct DetalhesFilme {

let id: Int
let titulo: String
let nota: Float
let ano: String
let descricao: String
let posterPath: String
let background: String

init(dados: [String: Any]) {

    let media = dados["vote_average"] as! NSNumber
    nota = media.floatValue
    titulo = dados["title"] as! String
    ano = dados["release_date"] as! String
    descricao = dados["overview"] as! String
    posterPath = dados["poster_path"] as! String
    background = dados["backdrop_path"] as! String
    id = dados["id"] as! Int

}
```

E fiz uma outra class que faz a requesicao na API. É aqui que está dando erro, no let id = idFilme?.id

Está aparecendo "Constant 'idFilme' used before being initialized".

```
class DetalhesAPI {

class func requisicao(completation: @escaping ([DetalhesFilme]) -> Void) {

    let idFilme: DetalhesFilme?
    let id = idFilme?.id   //Constant 'idFilme' used before being initialized
    let filmeDetalhes: [DetalhesFilme] = []

    Alamofire.request("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(id)?api_key=4b7fdfc0addcfa48e0168d4bcd77206f", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let resposta = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                guard let detalhesLista = resposta as? [[String: Any]] else {
                    return
                }

                completation(filmeDetalhes)

            }
        case .failure:
            print(response.error!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre pois este objeto esta vazio, ele não foi inicializado, você esta apenas declarando a variável. Você deve passar um id como parâmetro nesta função para que a chamada retorne o detalhe do filme que vocês está esperando como:

```swift
class func requisicao(id: Int, completation: @escaping (Result<DetalhesFilme>) -> Void) { ...
```

Aproveitando ja deixo algumas melhorias para facilitar o uso deste código, a primeira é usar o protocolo Codable para facilitar a conversão da resposta para Objeto, segue o código para a classe:

```
struct DetalhesFilme: Codable {

    let id: Int
    let titulo: String
    let nota: Float
    let ano: String
    let descricao: String
    let posterPath: String
    let background: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case titulo = "title"
        case nota = "vote_average"
        case ano = "release_date"
        case descricao = "overview"
        case posterPath = "poster_path"
        case background = "backdrop_path"
    }
}
```

Outra coisa importante é colocar o .responseData no lugar de .responseJSON pois facilitara na conversão da resposta para objeto:

```
class DetalhesAPI {

    class func requisicao(id: Int, completation: @escaping (Result<DetalhesFilme>) -> Void) {

        Alamofire.request("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(id)?api_key=4b7fdfc0addcfa48e0168d4bcd77206f", method: .get).responseData { (response) in
             switch response.result {
                        case .success(let data):
                            do {
                                let detail = try JSONDecoder().decode(DetalhesFilme.self, from: data)
                                completation(.success(detail))
                            } catch {
                                 completation(.failure(error))
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            completation(.failure(error))
                        }
                    }
        }
}
```

Utilização do codigo:

```
DetalhesAPI.requisicao(id: 32) { (result) in
    switch(result){
    case .success(let detalhe):
        // Aqui você tem o objeto recebido
        print(detalhe)
    case .failure(let error):
        // Aqui você trata o erro caso ocorra
        print(error)
    }
}
```